# How to rename HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I am cloning a table row to create a new row in the table. My problem is that when I clone, all the html elements get the same name as the ones in the previous row. I am using this code:

```
function incrCapexNode()
{
  var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
  var table = document.getElementById("capex_table"); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
  clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents

  table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

Can you please help me in renaming the html elements in the new row created.

Comment: When you say "renaming the HTML elements" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: He means give each cloned element a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I had to do this all I did was introduce a unique variable to the name to uniquely identify it. So the name becomes x123 and the next one is x124 etc.
You could do this with a guid but it depends on how unique your data is.

Answer (score 0):

You should not append the row to the table using *appendChild* as it will throw an error in most versions of IE, append it to the *tbody* element instead:

```
table.tBodies[0].appendChild(clone);
```

For the *id* (not name), work out a scheme using an incrementing value to ensure each row has a unique id. If you analyse your requirements, you may not need an id anyway.

Comment: yeah, thanks Rob, I don't need the id, but is there a way to rename the HTML elements. Sorry, I am bit new to JS. Trying to work out on this.

Comment: By renaming the HTML element, I mean html element to have unique id.

Comment: You can just use the same index method as for the row (or even use the `row.rowIndex` perhaps). You can get all the element decendents of the row using `row.getElementsByTagName('*')` then just iterate over the returned [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) changing any element with an *id* to a suitable value.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I did exactly the way you described and it worked.